# What is the cost of increasing the number of register names?

Tags: cpu, computer-architecture, register, instruction-set, register-file

Increasing the number of registers in a CPU, has the upside that more values can be kept in registers instead of having to spill to stack. It has some downsides, one of which is that more instruction bits are needed for specifying registers, potentially reducing code density.

In an in-order CPU, another downside is straightforward: more registers take more chip area. This was significant in the early days of microprocessors (e.g. if you look at a die photo of an ARM-1, the two biggest things on the chip are the barrel shifter and the register bank), though is much less significant after the 1980s.

In an out of order CPU, it's more complicated: architectural registers are names which are mapped on the fly to physical registers; for example, x64 has sixteen integer registers, but a modern x64 chip may rename these to any of somewhere in the range of one or two hundred physical registers.

As I understand it, once you go out of order, increasing the number of architectural registers then has the downside that it makes the job of the renaming circuitry harder, by increasing the  number of names it needs to keep track of.

This must've been particularly bad for the Itanium, which started off with 128 each of integer and floating-point architectural registers on the expectation that the explicit scheduling would allow it to stay in order; then that didn't work as well as hoped, and the next implementation had to go out of order anyway.

Is there a way to quantify, even to an order of magnitude, just what it costs in terms of what limiting resource (chip area, cycle time, power consumption?) to increase the number of architectural registers in an out of order CPU from 16 to 32 to 64 to 128?

Comment: A large register set slows task swaps and uses more instruction bits to encode the register number of several registers.

Comment: @user_1818839 Good point! So at what sort of size does a register file start becoming the limiting factor on clock speed? It seems like that should apply to physical rather than architectural registers, and chip designers do make physical register files quite large, so it's not much of a limit?

Comment: @user_1818839, it's the other way around. The architecture and design lead to an attainable clock frequency. Obviously, during the planning and design process, all of the characteristics are traded off against each other to meet whatever design targets the project started with. But the clock frequency will be a consequence of the architecture. Many good architectures of the past have done better on lower clocks speeds than their competition. BTW, register files can be and are implemented in small duplicated (for multi read ports) RAMs, avoiding the large slow muxes that DFF arrays would need.

Comment: @user_1818839, oh, all of what I said is true, not just part of it. I can't see how your comment relates to exactly what I was saying or to your original comment, though.